# Coroutine stops working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have two scripts with a coroutine in them. It works perfectly fine in the first one, but not in the second one, for no apparent reason.

**It works in this one:**

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects;

public class GameStartController : MonoBehaviour {
    public Button startButton;
    public GameObject cubeSpawner;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start() {
        startButton = startButton.GetComponent<Button>();   
    }

    public void StartGame() {
        EnableCubeSpawner();
        SpawnStartingCubes();
        HideStartMenu();
        StartCoroutine("FocusCamera");
        PlayBackgroundMusic();
    }

    // Enables the cube spawner, so it can start spawning cubes
    private void EnableCubeSpawner() {
        cubeSpawner.SetActive(true);
    }

    private void SpawnStartingCubes() {
        cubeSpawner.GetComponent<CubeSpawner>().GenerateStartingCubes();
    }

    private void PlayBackgroundMusic() {
        var audio = GameObject.FindWithTag("Audio").GetComponent<AudioController>();
        audio.PlayBackgroundMusic();
    }

    private void HideStartMenu() {
        startButton.transform.parent.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().interactable = false;
        startButton.transform.parent.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 0f;
    }

    private IEnumerator FocusCamera() {
        var camera = GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
        var velocity = 0f;

        while (Mathf.Abs(camera.GetComponent<DepthOfField>().aperture) > 0.001f) {
            Debug.Log(Mathf.Abs(camera.GetComponent<DepthOfField>().aperture));

            camera.GetComponent<DepthOfField>().aperture = Mathf.SmoothDamp(camera.GetComponent<DepthOfField>().aperture, 0f, ref velocity, 0.3f);
            yield return null;
        }

        camera.GetComponent<DepthOfField>().aperture = 0f;
    }
}
```

**The coroutine works just fine and the camera aperture goes smoothly from 0.6 to 0.**

**However in the second script this doesn't happen:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects;

public class GameOverController : MonoBehaviour {
    public void EndGame() {
        StartCoroutine("UnfocusCamera");
        DisableCubeSpawner();
        DestroyAllCubes();
        StopBackgroundMusic();
        ShowStartMenu();
    }

    // Disables the cube spawner, so it can stop spawning cubes
    private void DisableCubeSpawner() {
        var cubeSpawner = GameObject.FindWithTag("CubeSpawner");
        cubeSpawner.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void DestroyAllCubes() {
        var gameObjects = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject));

        foreach (var gameObject in gameObjects.Where(gameObject => gameObject.name.Contains("Cube"))) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void StopBackgroundMusic() {
        var audio = GameObject.FindWithTag("Audio").GetComponent<AudioController>();
        audio.StopBackgroundMusic();
    }

    private void ShowStartMenu() {
        var startMenu = GameObject.FindWithTag("StartMenu");
        startMenu.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().interactable = true;
        startMenu.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 1f;
    }

    private IEnumerator UnfocusCamera() {
        var camera = GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
        var velocity = 0f;

        while (camera.GetComponent<DepthOfField>().aperture < 0.6f) {
            Debug.Log(Mathf.Abs(camera.GetComponent<DepthOfField>().aperture));
            camera.GetComponent<DepthOfField>().aperture = Mathf.SmoothDamp(camera.GetComponent<DepthOfField>().aperture, 0.6f, ref velocity, 0.3f);
            yield return null;
        }

//        camera.GetComponent<DepthOfField>().aperture = 0f;
    }
}
```

**It only works for one frame (aperture goes from 0 to 0.03), and then just stops.
Why is this happening?**

Comment: @31eee384 Thank you. The problem is with `Destroy()` in `DestroyAllCubes()`. Is there a reason why the coroutine stops after this? The script is not in the scene itself so it can't get destroyed or anything.

Comment: i think the while in your second loop needs to be like this:   `while (camera.GetComponent<DepthOfField>().aperture <= 0.6f)`

Comment: @Calleth'Zion' Same thing, The `=` doesn't have to do anything with the problem at hand.

Comment: well yeah, I just missunderstood the SmoothDamp function, whats is weird  is that the first coroutine works one thing I noted is that the yield return breaks the coroutine so if it is called after the first lap on the while it will stop... maybe try just to take out the yield return null from the while loop and add the Time.DeltaTime parameter to the SmoothDamp function

Comment: I turned my earlier comment into an answer. For any further help I think you'll need to provide more context. Where *is* the script? What game objects exist, which ones are being deleted?

Comment: Did you check the `GameObject` in hierarchy in which this script is attached? Is it alive after this problem?

Comment: Can you verify the status of the `GameObject` the `GameOverController` script is attached to in the scene once the aperture has stopped unfocusing prematurely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you destroy (or disable) a game object, coroutines running on components attached to it will stop. I'm unable to find a primary source on this, but here are two other stack overflow questions where this was the problem:

- [Unity3d coroutine stops after while-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138943/unity3d-coroutine-stops-after-while-loop)
- [Unity - WaitForSeconds() does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552235/unity-waitforseconds-does-not-work)

The coroutine stops because the GameObject your `GameOverController` is attached to is destroyed. Presumably Unity checks whether an object still exists before resuming its coroutine, and if the object is destroyed, Unity does not continue to execute it.

To fix this problem, you can delay destroying the GameObject until the animation is complete (perhaps putting the destroy code after the while loop in the coroutine) or put the component on a GameObject that won't be destroyed.

Comment: The script is not attached to anything though

Comment: @Milen Then how is it running? `MonoBehaviors` are always attached a game object--you must be misinterpreting how it's created.

Comment: By "not attached" I mean it not being attached to a game object in the inspector.

Comment: @Milen Where *is* it then? How is it running?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases this mean that your object or script became inactive. Best way to check this is to add OnDisable() method to your script and call logging from it